# Axon Saga to Query Another Microservice

Tags: axon, saga, axon-framework

When a `@SagaEventHandler` needs to fetch data from another Microservice that also uses Axon Framework, is it a good practice to use `QueryGateway` to query another Microservice? Or it is better to use something like `RestTemplate` to call another Microservice from a `@SagaEventHandler` method?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you can go any way as both of them have pros and cons.

But, since you are already using Axon, I would go with that because of the benefits of location transparency and all the types of query you get by granted from AxonFramework (point-to-point, scatter gather and subscription query).

Bear in mind that, when using "components" on the Saga, make them transient to not have them serializable.